# How does a lock work in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

Suppose I have 2 instances of a `CustomThread` and one common object instance called `printer`. Inside the `print` method of `printer`, if I do a `lock.lock()` and `lock.unlock()` at the end, how does this work?

```
private class Printer{

        private final Lock mutex = new ReentrantLock(true);

        public void print(int thread){
            try {
                mutex.lock();
                for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
                    System.out.println(String.format("Printing: %d for Thread: %d", i, thread));
                }
            } catch(Exception e){

            } finally {
                mutex.unlock();
            }
        }
    }
```

I will call this method from 2 of my thread objects.

My question is, how does the method `lock` itself? Isn't a lock based on a thread? Maybe I am confusing the core idea here. When I do a lock inside a method, what does it mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can think of it as if a lock has a field called `owner`, which is a `Thread`.

When `lock()` is called, and `owner` is `null`, `owner` is assigned to the calling thread. When `unlock()` is called, `owner` is reset to `null`.

When `lock()` is called, and `owner` is not `null` (and not the current thread, since the lock is re-entrant), the calling thread blocks until another thread relinquishes ownership and it can be assigned as the new owner.

The additional complication is that the check for the current ownership, and the conditional assignment of the current thread as the new owner, both have to be seen to occur atomically by other threads. This preserves the integrity of the lock.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. So this lock can detect which thread is calling due to internal specs? Secondly, if I have locked and then another thread calls the same method and tries locking again what happens?

Comment: @Bhatnag I'm not sure what you mean by internal specs, but any method can determine which thread is invoking it by calling [`Thread.currentThread()`.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#currentThread--) Is that what you mean?

Comment: I mean to ask, let's say I have locked using T1, then another thread T2 tries calling lock again, what exactly happens in this case? Is this call just queued for when the lock is freed by T1?

Comment: @Bhatnag The scheduler will suspend execution of T2 until it can acquire the lock. The precise nature of this "scheduler" and exactly how it suspends operation depends on the implementation of the JVM and likely the underlying platform. But at the abstraction level of the Java runtime, T2 stops running until it acquires the lock.

Comment: Thanks! your explanation was great! Just one more doubt. Can this ever get screwed up? Ie, when would `Mutex.lock()` throw an exception? I can't think of a case

Comment: @Bhatnag The regular `lock()` method won't throw an exception; it will patiently block until it gets the lock, even if other threads call `interrupt()` on the waiting thread. There are some variants that support timing out, or that respond to interruption; if callers are interrupted while waiting on these, an `InterruptedException` is raised.

Comment: Great, Thanks a lot!